# Добавление в календарь напоминания о каком-либо событии

Tags: android, java

Задание: добавить в календарь напоминание о каком-либо событии.
В итоге получился такой код:

```
public class FLYNOTE_Calendar extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String calName;
    String calID;
     Uri calendars;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);

        String calId = null;
        String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "name" };

        Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, projection, "selected=1", null, null);
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.set(2012, 8, 12, 10, 0, 0);

        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        end.set(2012, 8, 12, 11, 0, 0);

        long startTime = start.getTimeInMillis();       
        long endTime = end.getTimeInMillis();

        if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {

            int nameColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("name"); 
            int idColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("_id");

            do{
                calName = managedCursor.getString(nameColumn);
                calId = managedCursor.getString(idColumn);

                event.put("calendar_id", calId);
                event.put("title", "Название");
                event.put("description", "Описание");
                event.put("eventLocation", "Днепропетровск");
                event.put("dtstart", startTime );
                event.put("dtend", endTime);

                Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
                Uri calUri = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
            }
            while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
            }
              }
}
```

Но ничего не происходит. В календарь событие не добавлено. Я что-то пропустил, или может оно по другому работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Включите в манифесте пермишен на работу с календарем:

```
android.permission.READ_CALENDAR
android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
```

И еще этот API работает только под >=2.1